# Need help creating a code that instances an object along a surface evenly

Tags: python, maya

I'm pretty new to coding and I need to create a code that generates an object along the normal of a selected geo surface.

Anything to start me on the right path would be appreciated.

I initially tried to use duplicate, but I was told that command instancer is the better option.

```
def ChainmailSurfaceGenerator():
    thing = MC.ls(sl=True)
    print thing
    if not thing:
        MC.error("select a torus")

    #create a group for your chainmail*
    grp = MC.group(empty=True, name=thing[0] + '_grp#'

#create hierarchy of grouped toruses

MC.polyTorus( radius=1, n = 'chainmail_link')
MC.duplicate('chainmail_link')

#query the direction of UV normals off the face
#lessen the amount of geometry if its too dense
#try it out on a plane surface first
#keep things simple early
#what if chains don't connect perfectly? add a randomizer so that the chains aren't all completely symmetrical
#don't use MC.duplicate; use Instancer
```

Comment: you can use nearestPointOnMesh

Answer (score 0):

You might not actually need to query the UV direction of the target geometry.
Try looking into the commands for constraints like cmds.normalConstraint or cmds.geometryConstraint.  As for the number of objects to make, consider using a for loop in a range of how many objects you want.  If you want to apply a random rotation, I would recommend using a group or a locator as an offset for transforming the group around (either with setAttr or xform) so that you can move the group while maintaining the ability to rotate the duplicate in it's y axis.  If you go the route of normal constraints, be sure to use the aim flag to point the object up in its y axis!  Googling the commands should come up with documentation on what flags to use.